# How to make shell agnostic a Husky hook?

Tags: git, sh, lerna, husky

This is the pre-commit hook

```sh
#!/bin/sh
. "$(dirname "$0")/_/husky.sh"

lerna run --concurrency 1 --stream precommit --since HEAD --exclude-dependents
```

It fails due to

```sh
.husky/pre-commit: 4: lerna: not found
husky - pre-commit hook exited with code 127 (error)
```

But it works if I change it to ZSH (always calling husky.sh script)

```sh
#!/bin/zsh
```

EDIT: adding the husky.sh script

```sh
#!/bin/sh
if [ -z "$husky_skip_init" ]; then
  debug () {
    [ "$HUSKY_DEBUG" = "1" ] && echo "husky (debug) - $1"
  }

  readonly hook_name="$(basename "$0")"
  debug "starting $hook_name..."

  if [ "$HUSKY" = "0" ]; then
    debug "HUSKY env variable is set to 0, skipping hook"
    exit 0
  fi

  if [ -f ~/.huskyrc ]; then
    debug "sourcing ~/.huskyrc"
    . ~/.huskyrc
  fi

  export readonly husky_skip_init=1
  sh -e "$0" "$@"
  exitCode="$?"

  if [ $exitCode != 0 ]; then
    echo "husky - $hook_name hook exited with code $exitCode (error)"
    exit $exitCode
  fi

  exit 0
fi
```

How do I make it shell agnostic? I'm using a lerna monorepo

Comment: I don't know how we're supposed to answer this if we don't know what's in `husky.sh`. A [mre] needs to be complete enough to test on its own.

Comment: (mind, `husky.sh` is misnamed if it _doesn't_ work with `/bin/sh` -- it should be `husky.zsh` if it uses zsh-isms, `husky.bash` if it uses bashisms, etc; `husky.sh` implies compatibility with _all_ POSIX-family shells -- a set that includes ash, dash, bash and ksh, but _not_ zsh except when running in compatibility mode).

Comment: (...and a question about `/bin/sh` shouldn't be tagged `bash`; `/bin/sh` is POSIX sh -- even if it's a symlink to bash or zsh, it'll be bash or zsh _running in POSIX sh compatibility mode_, so the `sh` tag should be used).

Comment: Anyhow, is `husky.sh` what's responsible for editing the PATH to include the location of `lerna` (or defining a `lerna` function)? If it's not we need to start looking from a completely different direction (most likely shell initialization code -- dependence on execution of `ZSH_ENV`, f/e)

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I have added the husky.sh script. It's weird that if I remove the call to husky.sh, then the hook no longer works. Even with `#!/bin/zsh`. So that answers your question of the path to include the location of lerna.

Comment: That's definitely not POSIX-compliant code -- `readonly` isn't present in the POSIX sh specification. I would _guess_, though it's only a guess, that `. ~/.huskyrc` is the part you actually need. But if you want to make it portable, take out the `readonly`s.

Comment: Also, there are some bugs in there that http://shellcheck.net/ will find.

Comment: BTW, consider putting `set -x` in your script (above the `.` command) to enable tracing, so you can see exactly where things bail out.

Comment: @MarcesDan did you manage to solve this? I'm using lerna globally to bypass this, but this is not a solution I'm proud of; and I don't like the idea of calling npx either

Comment: @darksoulsong Im still using `#!/bin/zsh` to bypass the issue. But one of my co-workers seems to have fixed it, using nvm.

Answer (score 4):

The code in question uses the `readonly` command. This is not part of the POSIX sh specification.

Thus, on a baseline POSIX shell, `readonly hook_name="$(basename "$0")"` is not guaranteed to set `hook_name` at all. Take out the `readonly`. (Also, I'd recommend against depending on behavior of `$0`; as described in [BashFAQ #28](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/028), it's unreliable).

`export readonly` also isn't POSIX-y; take out the `readonly` there as well.

Consider ditching `husky.sh` entirely and just sourcing in `"$HOME/.huskyrc"` directly.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
npx lerna run --concurrency 1 --stream precommit --since HEAD --exclude-dependents
```

Answer (score -7):

Use this command works for me :-

```
git commit -m "message" --no-verify
```

Comment: Bypassing Husky does nothing to fix this topic's issue.